# Do we need to set up Disaster Recovery(DR) plan for Azure Active Directory B2c in Azure Site Recovery?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-site-recovery

I am not able to find the options available for Azure Ad B2c(adb2c) for Disaster Recovery

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's available, as B2C is separate from AAD, coincidentally they share the same database (AAD) but B2C uses a lot of extensions on top of that.

Site Recovery is for AAD and DNS and users and computer accounts.

For B2C the best solution is to handle all config through code, and make your own functional backup of users. B2C has it's own redundency and uptime, but that is only technical.

Even if you would get the Site Recovery working on the underlying AAD of B2C, it will probably not sync the B2C config